# Import XML into Access database (transform multi-attributed child nodes)

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt-1.0

I have read up on some similar threads (much appreciation for all previous efforts documented) and pieced together most of my solution, however, I'm stumped on one thing.  I have a Student attribute that contains two Name attributes, used in two separate contexts (Student and Student/Guardian).  I associated a unique student ID with the Name attribute for the Student context, however, the import into Access lumps the Name values for both Student and Guardian attributes into the same table.  Also, the Guardian attribute is represented in a table, but it is disconnected from its Name attribute.  My XML file structure is as follows (please note: I have no control over its input structure; it's provided to me by an external system):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:SchoolUpload xmlns:ns1="http://ontario.ca">
    <ns1:Metadata>
        <ns1:CreateDate>2017-03-09</ns1:CreateDate>
        <ns1:CreateTime>22:45:53</ns1:CreateTime>
        <ns1:CreatedBy>Dave P</ns1:CreatedBy>
        <ns1:ContactPhone type="WORK">123-345-5678</ns1:ContactPhone>
        <ns1:ContactEmail>davep@email.com</ns1:ContactEmail>
    </ns1:Metadata>
    <ns1:School>
        <ns1:SchoolNumber>123456789</ns1:SchoolNumber>
        <ns1:Name>School Name</ns1:Name>
        <ns1:Students>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:OEN>10101010</ns1:OEN>
                <ns1:Grade>GR9</ns1:Grade>
                <ns1:Class>9E</ns1:Class>
                <ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:First>Student1</ns1:First> 
                    <ns1:Middle>Middle</ns1:Middle>
                    <ns1:Last>Surname</ns1:Last>
                </ns1:Name>
                <ns1:AliasName>
                    <ns1:First>Red</ns1:First>
                    <ns1:Last>Blue</ns1:Last>
                </ns1:AliasName>/>
                <ns1:Gender>M</ns1:Gender>
                <ns1:BirthDate>1991-10-29</ns1:BirthDate>
                <ns1:Language>en</ns1:Language>
                <ns1:Guardian>
                    <ns1:Name>
                        <ns1:First>Primary</ns1:First>
                        <ns1:Last>Guardian</ns1:Last>
                    </ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Relationship>MOTHER</ns1:Relationship>
                    <ns1:Phone type="HOME">111-111-1111</ns1:Phone>
                </ns1:Guardian>
                <ns1:Guardian>
                    <ns1:Name>
                        <ns1:First>Secondary</ns1:First>
                        <ns1:Last>Guardian</ns1:Last>
                    </ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Relationship>FATHER</ns1:Relationship>
                    <ns1:Phone type="HOME">222-222-2222</ns1:Phone>
                </ns1:Guardian>
                <ns1:Address>
                    <ns1:Unit>2404</ns1:Unit>
                    <ns1:StreetNumber>1515</ns1:StreetNumber>
                    <ns1:StreetName>Main</ns1:StreetName>
                    <ns1:StreetType>Street</ns1:StreetType>
                    <ns1:City>Guelph</ns1:City>
                    <ns1:Province>ON</ns1:Province>
                    <ns1:PostalCode>N5N5N5</ns1:PostalCode>
                </ns1:Address>
                <ns1:Phone type="HOME">333-333-3333</ns1:Phone>
            </ns1:Student>
        </ns1:Students>
    </ns1:School>
</ns1:SchoolUpload>
```

The XSLT file I'm using is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:ns1="http://ontario.ca"  exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

 <xsl:template match="ns1:Student">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:School/ns1:SchoolNumber"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:Student/ns1:Name">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:Student/ns1:OEN"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:AliasName|ns1:Guardian|ns1:Address">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:Student/ns1:OEN"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code results in Access creating 8 tables (School, which links to Student, which subsequently links to various Student-related tables), however, I'm at a total loss as to how to ***put the Guardian's First [name] and Last [name] into the Guardian table (as is, those two attributes are being put into the Name table (which is associated to the Student). The Guardian table that is created should contain the following fields: OEN, Relationship, Phone [and Type], First [name of Guardian] and Last [name of Guardian]).***

EDIT: Guardian node's transformed XML would look something like:

```
<ns1:Guardian>  
   <ns1:FirstName>Primary</ns1:FirstName>
   <ns1:LastName>Guardian</ns1:LastName>
   <ns1:Relationship>MOTHER</ns1:Relationship>
   <ns1:Phone>111-111-1111</ns1:Phone>
   <ns1:PhoneType>HOME</ns1:PhoneType>
</ns1:Guardian>
```

Comment: Do you know what the result of the transformation should look like? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: Hello Michael.  Thank you for your response.  I have edited my post above (bold/italicized) to describe how the transformation should appear.  I hope it is clear.  Best regards, Dave.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't tell me much; please post the exact XML code you expect to get as the result of the transformation.

Comment: Hello Michael.  I'm a total newbie at XML (I've just been tasked to import the XML source data into an Access database so that can then be queried, etc.), so please forgive my poor explanation.  Anyway, I hope the edit above clarifies.  Thanks again for your follow up.  D.

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about Access. In order to hep you get the result you want, I need to see the exact (and full) result you want. Currently, I cannot tell where in the overall hierarchy the Guardian nodes are supposed to be.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just assumed (based on other threads and responses similiar to this issue) that you would copy and paste my xml and xlst code segments and import using Access XML import wizard to see the resulting tables that are created.  I apologise for confusing this issue; this is the first time I've ever posted (I found this site doing a Google search on the question description above).  I will re-post this in an Access thread.  Thank you for your feedback.  Best regards, D.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (!) you want to change:

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:Student">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:School/ns1:SchoolNumber"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

to:

```
 <xsl:template match="ns1:Student">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:School/ns1:SchoolNumber"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ns1:Guardian)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:Guardian"/>
 </xsl:template>
```